# Ошибка vk_api __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given при попытке получить текст сообщения в личке

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь получить текст сообщения в личке:

```py
vk=vk_api.VkApi(token='ТОКЕН').get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me:
                print(event.text)
```

Токен получил через Kate mobile, если не использовать лонгполл, то отправляет сообщения нормально, через пользователя, а не через группу.

При запуске появляется ошибка:

```
vk_api __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Как еще можно получить текст входящего в личку сообщения?

Answer (score 0):

Просто убери `.get_api()` из `vk=vk_api.VkApi(token='ТОКЕН').get_api()`

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

token = 'YOU_TOKEN'

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            print(event.text)
```

Отправь сообщение, получишь вывод в консоле.
Я надеюсь это то что ты искал.